# Not able to open zip file with Jd- GUI java decompiler

Tags: java, decompiling, jd-gui

I am trying to save all sources using Jd GUI 0.3.5.
I am on mac and installed latest Java 8.

When i click save all sources then zip file is created.

But when i double click on it . It says

```
Unable to expand , Error 20 not a directory
```

Single files are working fine

UPdate

I mean i am decompiling the .class files . When i open one class file then it shows in the left bar the complete com package. Then i select that com in tree and then in the options above. It says save all sources . Then it shows export progess bar saying exporting to class.src.zip. Then when i double click on that zip file then i get error. If i save single class file then it saves fine as .java but not athe whole packaage. The packagae is not in jar format but open folder with class files

Comment: What says that? JD? JD to decompile zip files? What are you trying to do?

Comment: JD-GUI decompiles JARs and gives you source code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I mean i am decompiling the .class files . When i open one class file then it shows in the left bar the complete `com` package. Then i select that `com` in tree and then in the options above. It says save all sources . Then it shows export progess bar saying exporting to `class.src.zip`. Then when i double click on that zip file then i get error. If i save single class file then it saves fine as .java but not athe whole packaage. The packagae is not in jar format but open folder with class files

Comment: did you find a solution for this?